# C - Retirar elemento do resultado

Tags: c

Como faço para retirar os 0.00000 printados na resposta desse programa após as funções `idealBrutus` e `idealOlivia` são chamados na função `main`?

Percebi que se, por exemplo, mudar a linha 59 do original para:

```
printf ("%s", idealBrutus (imcBrutus,pBrutus, hBrutus, strBrutus));
```

receberei um (`null`) após a função ser `idealBrutus` ser utilizada.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>

float imc (float peso, float altura)
{
    return ( peso / pow(altura, 2));
}

float idealBrutus (float imc, float peso_inicial,float altura, char nome[100])
{
    float dif_para_o_peso_ideal;
    float peso_ideal;

    peso_ideal = 25 * pow(altura,2);

    dif_para_o_peso_ideal = abs(peso_ideal - peso_inicial);

    printf ("Para ficar com o Imc ideal %s ", nome);
    printf ("deve perder %f kg \n", dif_para_o_peso_ideal);

}

float idealOlivia  (float imc, float peso_inicial,float altura, char nome[100])
{
    float dif_para_o_peso_ideal;
    float peso_ideal;

    peso_ideal = 18.5 * pow(altura,2);

    dif_para_o_peso_ideal = abs(peso_ideal - peso_inicial);

    printf ("Para ficar com o Imc ideal %s ", nome);
    printf ("deve ganhar %f kg \n", dif_para_o_peso_ideal);

}

int main ()
{
    char strBrutus[100] = "Brutus";
    float hBrutus;
    float pBrutus;
    float imcBrutus;

    char strOlivia[100] = "Olivia";
    float hOlivia;
    float pOlivia;
    float imcOlivia;

    pBrutus = 122;
    hBrutus = 1.84;

    pOlivia = 45;
    hOlivia = 1.76;

    imcBrutus = imc (pBrutus, hBrutus);
    imcOlivia = imc (pOlivia, hOlivia);

    printf ("O imc de Brutus e : %f \n", imcBrutus);
    printf ("%f", idealBrutus (imcBrutus,pBrutus, hBrutus, strBrutus));
    printf ("O imc de Olivia e : %f \n", imcOlivia);
    printf ("%f", idealOlivia (imcOlivia,pOlivia, hOlivia, strOlivia));

}
```

Comment: De todas as variáveis você quer tirar as casas depois da `,` ?

Comment: Ao rodar o código tenho o seguinte resultado: O imc de Brutus e : 36.034969
Para ficar com o Imc ideal Brutus deve perder 37.000000 kg
0.000000O imc de Olivia e : 14.527376
Para ficar com o Imc ideal Olivia deve ganhar 12.000000 kg
0.000000

Comment: Queria me livrar desses 0.000000 após o 37.000000 kg, para que o resultado fique :  36.034969 Para ficar com o Imc ideal Brutus deve perder 37.000000 kg O imc de Olivia e : 14.527376 Para ficar com o Imc ideal Olivia deve ganhar 12.000000 kg

Comment: Vou elaborar a resposta @LeandroSouza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Estava vendo seu código e percebi que você possuí uma dúvida em
>   relação as casas depois da `,` como elimina-las.

Então testei esse código e funcionou:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>

float imc (float peso, float altura)
{
    return ( peso / pow(altura, 2));
}

float idealBrutus (float imc, float peso_inicial,float altura, char nome[100])
{
    float dif_para_o_peso_ideal;
    float peso_ideal;

    peso_ideal = 25 * pow(altura,2);

    dif_para_o_peso_ideal = abs(peso_ideal - peso_inicial);

    printf ("Para ficar com o Imc ideal %s ", nome);
    printf ("deve perder %.0f kg \n", dif_para_o_peso_ideal);

}

float idealOlivia  (float imc, float peso_inicial,float altura, char nome[100])
{
    float dif_para_o_peso_ideal;
    float peso_ideal;

    peso_ideal = 18.5 * pow(altura,2);

    dif_para_o_peso_ideal = abs(peso_ideal - peso_inicial);

    printf ("Para ficar com o Imc ideal %s ", nome);
    printf ("deve ganhar %.0f kg \n", dif_para_o_peso_ideal);

}

int main ()
{
    char strBrutus[100] = "Brutus";
    float hBrutus;
    float pBrutus;
    float imcBrutus;

    char strOlivia[100] = "Olivia";
    float hOlivia;
    float pOlivia;
    float imcOlivia;

    pBrutus = 122;
    hBrutus = 1.84;

    pOlivia = 45;
    hOlivia = 1.76;

    imcBrutus = imc (pBrutus, hBrutus);
    imcOlivia = imc (pOlivia, hOlivia);

    printf ("O imc de Brutus e : %.0f \n", imcBrutus);
    printf ("%.0f", idealBrutus (imcBrutus,pBrutus, hBrutus, strBrutus));
    printf ("O imc de Olivia e : %.0f \n", imcOlivia);
    printf ("%.0f", idealOlivia (imcOlivia,pOlivia, hOlivia, strOlivia));

}
```

**O que eu fiz para dar certo a eliminação das casas após a `,` ?**

Acrescentei nos printf("%.0f");

**O porquê usar `%.0f` ao invés de simplesmente usar `%f`?**

Quando se coloca `%.` está limitando as casas depois do `.`

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, de fato o resultado ficou melhor sem as casas decimais. Só um adendo, nas linhas 59 e 61 do seu código revisado, coloquei "%." ao invés de "%f" para evitar que o resultado printe 0.00000 após , por exemplo, 37 kg, como sugerido pelo comentário do neto.

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário. Fico feliz em ter ajudado! Já editei as linhas na resposta!